# EF 6 not generating all inherited fields for some classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

```
public abstract class TableBase
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateInsert { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public AppUser UserInsert { get; set; }
    public AppUser UserUpdate { get; set; }        
}

public class AppUser:TableBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PasswordStored { get; set; }        
}

public class SandorTestDBContext : DbContext
{
    public SandorTestDBContext() : base("SandorTestDB")
    {    
    }

    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Given above classes, one would assume that the AppUser table in the SQLserver would include all fields of both classes. But the table is missing the UserUpdate_Id field.

```
TABLE [dbo].[AppUsers](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[LoginName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[PasswordStored] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[DateInsert] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DateUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
[UserInsert_Id] [int] NOT NULL
```

On the other hand, adding the following class:

```
public class Company : TableBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OldCompanyReference { get; set; }  
}
```

And adding the DbSet in the Context does generate all fields

```
public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

TABLE [dbo].[Companies](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[OldCompanyReference] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DateInsert] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DateUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
[UserInsert_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserUpdate_Id] [int] NULL,
```

So what Am I missing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing in common with inheritance - the same will happen if you remove inheritance and copy `TableBase` properties to `AppUser`.

The problem is that `AppUser` has 2 **self** references - `UserInsert` and `UserUpdate`. Since the first is marked as required and the second is optional, by convention EF maps them to a single one-to-one FK relationship with `UserUpdate` being the inverse navigation property of the `UserInsert`. Which of course is not your intention.

As usual when EF conventional mapping does not produce the desired result, you need to use data annotations and/or fluent API. In this particular case - fluent API. The bare minimum required is this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.UserInsert)
    .WithMany();
```

This way you are telling EF to create one-to-many relationship with `UserInsert` reference navigation property at the one side and no collection navigation property at the other side. The additional effect of this is that when EF finds the unmapped `UserUpdate` reference navigation property, by convention it would create another one-to-many unidirectional relationship. Which at the end will create the two FK columns as with non self referencing entity example.

Also note that in the self referencing entity `AppUser`, the `UserInsert` cannot be required, because otherwise you won't be able to create any `AppUser` record. That's why I used `HasOptional` rather than `HasRequired`, which  overrides the base class property `Required` data annotation just for that entity.